# Polygon with all sides with different lengths

Tags: terminology, polygons

I searched a lot but I could not figure out the property name of a polygon with all sides with different lengths.

First of all I am assuming that it is possible to have at least one configuration for each polygons with $n$ sides (with $n > 2$), with all of its side lengths different among them.

So, a square is a **equilateral** polygon due to all of its sides have the same length, however what is the property name of a polygon with the shape below? **Unequilateral**? I cannot find the correct word and I think that **scalene** is only applied to triangles. Thanks!

```
   8^0.5 /|
        / | 3
     1 |__|
        2
```

Comment: I would call them irregular polygons. BTW, equilateral triangle is also scalene.

Comment: The basic distinction is [regular vs irregular](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/polygons.html).

Comment: An irregular polygon can have side lengths being the same, for instance consider an irregular rhombus. He wants to know if there is a name for the property that the polygon has no two sides congruent. In the special case of triangles, this is called being **scalene**.  What about the general case for a polygon with an arbitrary number of sides?  I do not think there is a name for this, but you could always just extend the definition of scalene to all n-gons. In fact, even if you didn't make the definition explicit, I'm pretty sure people will know what you mean.

Comment: The problem is that I can have an irregular polygon with 2 equal sides and the remaining ones different, or am I wrong? It's just because I thought in Math there was already a name for each type/combination of numbers, functions, figures and so on and I am finding odd not having a name to this situation.